# Is there any service of Map and GPS Logger for IoT Devices as free?(like Azure Maps in Azure IoT Central)

Tags: data-visualization, iot, saas, azure-maps

I want to visualization latitude and longitude data taken from IoT Devices.
But I couldn't find service is able to plot GPS log data.
For example, AT&T M2X can visualization and log data that just sensor data (like humidity, temperature, and so on) but it can't visualize map from data.

At last found Azure Maps, but it needs to register the credit card.
If needed to pay for the amount of user data, but I want to start map visualization with no pay option setting first.

I desire service keeps below three points, 1. no need pay option setting first, 2. it can post data from HTTP protocol(GET/POST), 3. any kinds of map type is ok (google map, BingMap, OpenStreetMap, and so on)

I'm sorry that my English is so bad. 
I look forward to your reply. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to take a look at Data Studio (Google Cloud Platform). To get you started (no money) you should be able to create a spreadsheet with comma separated lat/long values, import it into Data Studio and get a visualization on a map of those positions.

Check it out [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7065037?hl=en).

I know you said being able to post via HTTP is a requirement (makes it harder to use this, but wanted to point it out as it's cool and I just learned about it too.

There's also the [Maps API](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/maps/) which can do it (I'm actually unsure of how "free" it is, but most of our APIs have free tiers for like, # of requests). This is do-able via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Maps is a part of Azure and the credit card is for Azure all up, not just Azure Maps. That said, Azure Maps also provides free monthly usage limits. Also, in Azure you can set a spending limit on your account. After adding your credit card, simply set your limit to 0 and you don't need to worry about paying. If you exceed the free limits, your account will simply stop working until the next month when you get a new set of free limits. Here is some documentation on how to set a spending limit in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-spending-limit